# How to set fourth image show as a half view in collectionview...?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I want to display last image show as half view in all layout. How can I do that?

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout)self.collectionViewFouth.collectionViewLayout; 
CGFloat availableWidthForCells = CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionViewFouth.frame) - flowLayout.sectionInset.left - flowLayout.sectionInset.right - flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing *2; 
cellWidth = availableWidthForCells / 4; 
flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellWidth);

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView )collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section { 
  return 15; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: I will set this method but some layouts show in half and non...


- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                   layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 15;
}

Comment: UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)self.collectionViewFouth.collectionViewLayout;
        CGFloat availableWidthForCells = CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionViewFouth.frame) - flowLayout.sectionInset.left - flowLayout.sectionInset.right - flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing *2;
        
        
        cellWidth = availableWidthForCells / 4;
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellWidth);

Comment: imo, you may post same project ex https://github.com/larsblumberg/selection-test

Answer (score 1):

Implement Collection View Flow Layout Delegate "UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout"

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                                    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let width = collectionView.frame.size.width/3.5 
        let height = 100
        return CGSize(width,100)

            }
```